# Which one should I use [import * as mod from 'module'] or [import mod from 'module']?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know 2 writing conventions of importing modules in ES2022 module.

```
import mod from 'module'
```

or

```
import * as mod from 'module'
```

It looks like the same movement.
What's the difference? And which one should I use?

Thanks

Comment: Which `'module'` are you importing in particular? What does it export?

Comment: Other than that it is simply a matter of naming preference. To give an example, I often import the fs lib using `import * as fs from 'node:fs'` because I am use to the commonjs syntax, however, I use const   `import { format } from 'node:util';` so I can shorten the length of the format method calls --> `format('foo %s', bar);` rather than `util.format('foo %s', bar);`

Comment: @J-D3V If the module has a default export, you can still use `mod.default` when using the star import

Comment: I assumed scss importing. Most library like 'React' suggest 'import React from 'react'' style, but scss import sample suggests 'import * as 'sample.scss' style. so I confused.

Comment: Well, don't do it that way, that import statement will through an error.

Comment: Im pretty sure thats not what they told you to do, anyways, I have to get back to my work. Look at there example again @Zweiweiss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former imports the default export. The latter imports *all* the named exports as well.

Which you use depends on what you want to do. There isn't a "right" approach.

#### module.js

```js
export const a = 'a';
export const b = 'b';
const c = 'c';
export default c;
```

#### index.js

```js
import x from './module.js';
import * as y from './module.js';

console.log({ x, y });
```

#### output

```
{
  x: 'c',
  y: [Module: null prototype] { a: 'a', b: 'b', default: 'c' }
}
```